# If Statement Nested with a Vlookup in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup, array-formulas

I am struggling with an `If` statement within a `Vlookup` for Google Sheets.

The current formula:

```
=IfError(ARRAYFORMULA(if(len($A3:$A),VLOOKUP($A3:$A,
{'Form responses 3'!$E2:$E,'Form responses 3'!$G2:$G},2,0),)))
```

So what the above does is look for a value in `A3:A` on another sheet, and if there is a match within `E:E`, return the value in the second column, or `G:G`.

The problem with the above formula is that in `A3:A` there can only be one unique value (being 1 - 36 as an example) BUT there is an issue with `G2:G` having multiple iterations of the same number which the `Vlookup` only takes the first value that is matched.

Therefore, I am trying to expand on the above formula by asking it to check for another unique before giving me a value.  Hence the below formula:

```
=IfError(ARRAYFORMULA(If('Form responses 3'!D:D=3,,
 if(len($A3:$A),VLOOKUP($A3:$A,{'Form responses 3'!$E2:$E,'
 Form responses 3'!$G2:$G},2,0),))))
```

So what this is now trying to do is check first to see `if D:D =3`, then do the `VLookup` mentioned above only `IF D:D is 3` (in this example).

I clearly am not doing the `If lookup for =3` correctly as when I enter the second formula into a cell I still get the first value matched and it is not taking into consideration to look for 3 first.

I'll be happy to share the sheet should anyone want to look at the formula in all its context.

Comment: If you post a link to a test sheet someone will help. Comment back to me when you do this and if no replies by tomorrow I will assist. To comment me put @bcperth as first characters in the comment and I will get the alert.

Comment: Thanks @bcperth.  For those that would like to see the test sheet, please see link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xo8edBZQ5bJXUqqGxqPMZeyrdAQgIFZzkgv7Dct1g0A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok I tried to access but permission denied. You need to make it public or grant access.

Comment: Apologies - my share settings are pretty tight.  I have given you access.  Thank you.

Comment: OK take a look at the reply below and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with the formula:

```
=IfError(ARRAYFORMULA(If('Form responses 3'!D:D=3,,
 if(len($A3:$A),VLOOKUP($A3:$A,{'Form responses 3'!$E2:$E,'
 Form responses 3'!$G2:$G},2,0),))))
```

is that `VLOOKUP()` can only have one search criterion. You are trying to simulate multiple criteria by preceding `VLOOKUP()` with an `IF()` statement. In some circumstance you may be able to achieve results, but you end up with formulas that are hard to understand and hard to debug.

Instead use the `QUERY()` function where you can have multiple criteria. `QUERY()` is much more flexible allowing multiple search criteria.

Its syntax is `QUERY(range, select statement, [headers])`

Here is a sample that gives the correct value of 87 in your example sheet.

```
=query('Form responses 3'!$A$2:$G$6,"select G where D="&B$1&" and E = "&A3&"",0)
```

**Explanation:**

`Form responses 3'!$A$2:$G$6`   --- Range to be selected

`"select G` --- Select column G from matching rows in range

`where D="&B$1&`" --- criteria to match column D in range to cell B1

`and`  --- logical `and` for additional criteria to follow

`E = "&A3&"" ---criteria to match column E in range to cell A3

I strongly recommend to learn `QUERY` and all the possibilities of the various `select` statements.

I added an additional `sheet8` to the linked sheet here to show the query in action. The above formula is in cell `E3` and gives the value `87` as you expected.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xo8edBZQ5bJXUqqGxqPMZeyrdAQgIFZzkgv7Dct1g0A/edit?usp=sharing

**Note:** If you are not familiar with QUERY I suggest do a tutorial first and learn its syntax. The example above is a bit advanced to start with ( ie selecting from one sheet, based on cell values in another).

Comment: thank you.  I have actually started to use queries alot in some other aspects of sheets that I am unpacking for different purposes.  I am also planning to go on a sql course to further my knowledge of databases and queries alike.  I appreciate you taking the time to point me in the right direction and am glad that I learnt something during this process.

Comment: There are any number of SQL tutorials on line and very good... Also if you like you can accept my answer by clicking on the tick near the vote up/dn arrows top left of reply :-).